# Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Got a new rails demo and i can't start the server
i tried "mysql -u root -p" and its didn't work
here is my database.yml:

default: &default

adapter: mysql2

encoding: utf8

pool: 5

username: root

password: ''

host: localhost

development:

<<: *default

database: buk_store_dev

production:

adapter: mysql2

host: 127.0.0.1

database: buk_store_production

Answer (score 0):

Check your root password on your MySQL server. Looks like you are using the wrong password.